# How to index/query nested documents in lucene 3.4?

Tags: lucene, nested, document

I'm looking for a way to understand how the newly implemented nested document feature works in lucene 3.4. There doesn't seem to be any tutorial available on the net yet considering that it's a very recent feature. Can somebody please demonstrate on how to index/query them? Would be very helpful, thanks a lot :-).

Ananth.

Comment: I have read Lucene supports nested documents through a feature called _index-time joining_. However, I could not find any tutorial nor a simple example on how a nested document can be created. Have you found any information about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just made a blog post about using BlockJoinQuery:

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/01/searching-relational-content-with.html